# React Native - Performance difference between Animated.View vs regular View component

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, react-native

Are there any performance impact when using animated components i.e Animated.View vs using regular component i.e View in react native if there are 0 animations involved?

code example:

```
<View>
    <Text>asd</Text>
</View>
```

Vs

```
<Animated.View>
    <Text>asd</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

I have never seen people mention any performance impact when using Animated components but then again if there are none, why hasn't React developers make all components Animated by default.

Comment: Did you compare it yourself? Show us your code.

Comment: No I did not, was just curious if anyone has an answer, looked for it via googling but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: i dont have a answer but, animation is still some work that is happening. when you dont have animation, that means, no work is happening. so, i will extend that, there is always a cost involved in using a animation versus not using it, and you should expect a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we have a component in which we update the Native View frequently using inline styles, using **`Animated.View`** along with the optional native driver saves a lot of re-renders.

**When we use `Animated.View`, the following process takes place behind the hood:**

- On animation start, `requestAnimationFrame` is fired in JS
- New positions are calculated in JS
- JS serializes new position values and sends them over to the react-native bridge
- On the other end of the bridge, Java (android) and C# (iOS) deserializes it and updates underlying Native View
- The frame is then updated on the screen.

As we can see, `Animated.View` styles don't trigger a re-render of React Native Components, that is why their use should be preferred over `<View />` in such situations to avoid wasted renders.

Ref: [https://tech.unacademy.com/10-ways-to-avoid-wasted-renders-in-react-native-app-part-2/][1]

Answer (score 0):

Animated is a wrapper, animated.  is biding the animated values to the props so they can do targeted native updates instead of react render to avoid cost on every frame.
So it’s better to use it if it’s animated. You can use if else strategy as a new component  if you want to call it once everywhere